# is there a way to skip archived concourse pipelines and unpause only un archived pipelines?

Tags: concourse, concourse-pipeline, concourse-git-resource, concourse-task, concourse-fly

I am getting below error while unpause all our concourse pipelines using this below command.

Command:    fly -t ci unpause-pipeline -a

```
unpaused 'pipeline-1'
unpaused 'pipeline-2'
unpaused 'pipeline-3'
unpaused 'pipeline-4'
unpaused 'pipeline-5'
error: Unexpected Response
Status: 409 Conflict
Body:
action not allowed for an archived pipeline
```

Is there a way to select only unarchived pipelines and unpause  OR   skip archived pipelines during this process.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [it's not a thing yet](https://github.com/concourse/concourse/blob/v7.6.0/fly/commands/unpause_pipeline.go#L54-L81), but your question would make for a great enhancement request if reported in [concourse/concourse](https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues).